# Brownian motion property

Tags: probability-theory

I was reading a book and I came across this part which says that a Brownian motion $B(t)$ has this property:
 $P\{B(1) >c \}> 0$ for any real number $c$.

I know that $B(0) = 0$ but I don't understand why the above statement is true? how we are sure about that ? 
Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

$B(1)$ is just a Gaussian with mean zero and variance $1$, hence
$$ \mathbb{P}(B(1)>c)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_c^{\infty}e^{-\frac{t^2}{2}}\;dt>0 $$

Answer (score 0):

We know that $B(1) \sim N(0,1)$. The support of the normal density is all $\mathbb R$ so there is a positive probability of $B(1)$ passing any threshold